# Multiple after_update callbacks with attribute change conditions are triggering only the first one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Multiple after_update callbacks with attribute change conditions are triggering only the first one.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :method_1, :if => proc{ |obj| obj.status_changed? && obj.status == 'PUBLISHED' }
  after_update :method_2, :if => proc{ |obj| obj.status_changed? && obj.status == 'PUBLISHED' && obj.name == 'TEST' }
  ...
end
```

`method_1` is triggered when a model object is updated:

```
Article.last.update_attributes(status: 'PUBLISHED', name: 'TEST')
```

While `method_2` is not triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use one callback with an `if...end` block to filter operations you want to perform in each cases.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :method_1, :if => proc{ |obj| obj.status_changed? && obj.status == 'PUBLISHED' }
  ...

  def method_1        
    if self.name == 'TEST'
      # stuff you want to do on method_2
    else
      # stuff you want to do on method_1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check the return values of your callbacks. If a `before_*` or `after_*` ActiveRecord callback returns false, all later callbacks in the chain are cancelled.

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) (see Canceling callbacks)

```
If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled.
```